# UICollectionView UIImageView images not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm having trouble getting some images to appear in a UICollectionView.
I can see the cells are being created, and if i set the image manually through the storyboard the image appears, but i can't get it to happen in the code

The collection view uses a custom cell, which is below

```
class CardsListCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

}]
```

The image is connected in the storyboard and the cell has the correct class set

The code for displaying the image

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CardsListCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardsListCell

        // Configure the cell

        var card : Card = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Card

        var img = UIImage(named: card.image)
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: img)

        cell.image = imageView


        return cell
    }
```

it looks like the image and image view is being created as i can print them out

Comment: are they sometimes appearing or *never* appearing?

Comment: you don't need to create UIImageView programatically. just set a image to cell's UIImageView, like `cell.image.image = img`

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. i removed the image view from code and set the cell.image.image and they show up